# How to make CSS animation to go past the top border of the page without using large top margins.as cover

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to modify a cool demo in codepen at this link http://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/BNNJjo
what I am trying is to make it work in fullscreen because the demo container only covers the middle part of the screen which is only 1/3 of the real estate.  I have tried modifying the CSS usiong this

```
    .wrapper {
  background: #50a3a2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 100%;   <--- 
  overflow: hidden;
```

When I do this it goes full screen but the animation stops irregularly at the top. Is there a way to make the animation go past screen without restricting the  container to 1/3 of the screen?

Comment: Remove `top: 50%`, `margin-top: 100%` and make `height: 100%`. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
  background: #50a3a2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pjgzBg)

Comment: Hi sir its full screen now but the animation stops at the top of the page I need the animation/boxes to go over the page not stop at the top.   I think that is the reason why the original example has a top margin to make an illusion that the boxes went over the page.  I want to achieve that without any top margins.